# Citrix Netscaler and Google Compute Engine

Tags: citrix, netscaler

Does Citrix Netscaler load balancer run in the Google Compute Environment ? Is it supported ? Is there a replacment for it ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

It is not on the [platforms list](https://www.citrix.com/products/netscaler-application-delivery-controller/platforms.html) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/i2aGY).)

It is supported [for Microsoft Azure](http://docs.citrix.com/en-us/netscaler/11/getting-started-with-vpx/deploy-vpx-on-azure.html).
And it is supported [for Amazon AWS](http://docs.citrix.com/en-us/netscaler/11/getting-started-with-vpx/install-vpx-on-aws.html)

Answer (score 0):

Netscaler is supported on all 3 major clouds (and some other platforms like nutanix). For google cloud you can find all the information here 
https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-adc/13/deploying-vpx/deploy-vpx-google-cloud.html